# Problema con fuentes en FPDF

Tags: php, poo, pdo, fpdf

Estoy tratando de generar un PDF, si lo creado todo en un mismo directorio no hay problema, el problema viene cuando llamo a la funcion que me va a generar dicho doc.

> Warning: include(font/helveticab.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/fpdf.php on line 1145
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'font/helveticab.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/fpdf.php on line 1145 FPDF
>   error: Could not include font definition file

Me da la sensación que al llamarlo desde otro archivo y carpeta no encuentra dicho doc.

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('include/crud_usuario.php');
require_once('include/class_usuario.php');


$crud = new CrudUsuario;
$usuario = new Usuario;
$usuario = $crud->obtenerUsuario($_GET['id_usuario']);
```

Y la función,

```
public function matricula(){
    $pdf = new PDF;
    $usuario = new Usuario;
    /*antes de AddPage para que se apliquen los cambios*/
    $pdf->SetTitle('Matricula - MC');
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(25);
    $pdf->SetRightMargin(25);
    /**/
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $y_axis_initial = 25;
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->InfoFicha($usuario);
    /*Lo guardamos el PDF con dni de la persona*/
    return $pdf->Output('matricula-'.$usuario->getDni().'.pdf','I');
}
```

Comment: Lo que parece estar ocurriendo, entre otras cosas, es que no puede incluir los archivos de fuente: `Failed opening 'font/helveticab.php'  ... Could not include font definition file ... ` ¿Qué hay en la línea `1145`?

Comment: Gracias y hola de nuevo. Pues la question es que ese es la clase de FPDF en dicha linea se encuentra esto: protected function _loadfont($font)
{
 // Load a font definition file from the font directory
 if(strpos($font,'/')!==false || strpos($font,"\\")!==false)
  $this->Error('Incorrect font definition file name: '.$font);
 include($this->fontpath.$font);
 if(!isset($name))
  $this->Error('Could not include font definition file');
 if(isset($enc))
  $enc = strtolower($enc);
 if(!isset($subsetted))
  $subsetted = false;
 return get_defined_vars();
}

Comment: No tengo ningún tipo de experiencia usando la clase `FPDF`, pero la lógica indica que la clase intenta cargar la clase cuyo nombre es `$font`, que es el dato que recibe en parámetro. ¿Sabes desde dónde se le está pasando ese parámetro a la clase? Parece que la clase está intentando cargar una fuente llamada `helveticab.php` y no la encuentra. Lo extraño es que en tu código tú pareces indicar que quieres la fuente `Arial`... por lo que no veo de dónde rayos puede salir `helveticab.php`
 ¿Estarás configurando bien el objeto? ¿La librería está actualizada?

Comment: Sí, así estoy que no entiendo de donde sale eso. Si voy a mirar bien que este todo al día, aunque fue implementado hace pocas semanas. Voy a ver

Comment: Hola! Sería bueno si nos muestras el código fuente de la clase donde ocurre el error (`fpdf.php`), por favor, ya que en tu comentario no se aprecia bien el código. (Edita tu pregunta y le agregas el código fuente ;) )

Comment: @quinqui Gracias por contestar, es tan largo que no me deja copiarlo, puedo hacerte un pastebin si estas de acuerdo.

Comment: Puede que sea un problema de la ruta, que no las estés indicando bien.  Al parecer, la clase intenta usar `helveticab.php` cuando el tipo de fuente que le has pedido no existe. Prueba a poner otro tipo de fuente que no sea `Arial`, por ejemplo: `Courier`  y revisa las rutas de tus `include`. **Has un `echo "Debo revisar esta ruta: ".FPDF_FONTPATH;`** y revisa que realmente la ruta que imprime esa constante **existe** en tu entorno.

Comment: Vale. Al cambiar de Arial a Courier nada sigue saliendo el mismo error. En cuanto al echo me manda lo siguiente Debo revisar esta ruta: font/. La carpeta existe y el archivo que no encuentra también.